# A group $G$ is locally cyclic if and only if $G$ is a union of a chain of cyclic subgroups ?

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, locally-cyclic-groups

Is it true that a group $G$ is locally cyclic if and only if $G$ is a union of a chain of cyclic subgroups ?

Comment: Well, clearly the union of a chain of cyclic groups is locally cyclic. I assume your troubles lie in proving / disproving the other direction?

Comment: @Arthur : yes off-course I am having difficulty with the converse part ...

Comment: If $G$ is countably generated then it should be true. If not then I don't really have any intuition what's going on...

Comment: Every strictly increasing chain of cyclic groups has (at most) countable length. This, any uncountable locally cyclic group will provide a counter example. Is your question about existence of such groups?

Comment: @studiosus : yes but $G$ is not cyclic ... I am not getting what you are saying :(

Comment: @studiosus : each of the subgroups in the union is cyclic I mean but not $G$ ...

Comment: @SebastianSchoennenbeck : I know that any torsion-free locally cyclic subgroup can be embedded in $\mathbb Q$ , so must be countably generated , so could you please elaborate on your comment that how can you prove it for countably generated groups ? ( as that takes care of a lot )

Answer (score 0):

As per the request in the comments, here is the proof in the case that $G$ is countably generated.

We choose a countable generating set $\{a_n~|~n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ of $G$ and define for $N \in \mathbb{N}$ the subgroup $C_N:=\langle a_1,...,a_N \rangle$.

Then $C_N$ is finitely generated hence cyclic and the set of all the $C_N$ forms a chain by construction. Moreover $\bigcup_N C_N$ contains a generating system for $G$ and thus coincides with $G$ which proves the assertion.